# lapply with eval are giving incorrect output, printing the dim of the data instead of the data itself

Tags: r, lapply

I basically want to perform the below Python operation, but in R

```
train['annotation']=train['annotation'].apply(eval)
```

So, I tried this:

```
train$annotation <- lapply(train$annotation, eval)
```

However, I am getting incorrect output. The output in Python for the annotation column is:

[image]

And in R, I am getting:

[image]

What is wrong with my R code?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Maybe you want `sapply` rather than `lapply`? Had to say without seeing the data.

Comment: Yes, sapply worked! Thank you!